# Struts 2 Display Issue with Spanish Text

Tags: java, character-encoding, struts2, html-entities

I have a Struts 2 application which has a Spanish property file used by Struts s:text tags. However, the resulting pages in the web browser have gibberish characters in them like this:

```
ContraseÃ±a:
```

The value in the property file is:

```
password = Contraseña
```

I initially thought that the problem was the encoding of my property file, but both Notepad++ and standard Windows notepad report that it is saved as UTF-8.

Is there anything else that I could do to fix the characters in my property files?

Comment: It's not just a matter of the property files (I'm only familiar with encoding via native2ascii), it's also the page encoding.

Comment: @Dave-Newton - At the start of my jsp pages, I have the following header: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> ......... is that sufficient to set the page encoding?

Comment: Anything else would probably solve the problem.

Comment: Ha! Now we all know your password !!  :>

Comment: Please refer to this GREAT answer from BalusC: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14178117/1654265 . Read it carefully, and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the browser, you should serve those characters as `HTML entity` like : 
`&ntilde;`, you may want to write them that way directly or have an tool to convert those values to `HTML entities`.

Also in the files to avoid issues with other developers and editors with not `UTF8`, the best way is to store those string in `Unicode` format, you can type them in your native language (Spanish for example) and after that run the `native2ascii` command to convert them to `unicode`...

The advantage with that is that everyone will be able to open the `.java` and `.jsp` files... if they want to work with the phrases, then they open the properties file...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the properties files are, by default, readed asuming that the encoding is ASCII, something that, really, sucks.

I've an unanswered question here regarding the same problem.

[Struts2: UTF .properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779037/struts2-utf-properties)

I know that ResourceBundle can manage UTF-8 files (I say in that question how to do it and put a link to a page in which is done and used un JSF) but no idea of how to do it in struts2