# Struts2: UTF .properties

Tags: java, utf-8, struts2, internationalization

Is there a way to load a UTF-8 encoded .properties file in Struts2?

I know that its posible to load a UTF-8 file in a ResourceBundle via implementing your Control that loads a UTF8 inputstream but how to use it in Struts2? (I found howto do it in JSF here:

http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/

but cannot figure how to do it in struts2)

PD: Also I know that I can use the native2ascii tool, but its... ugly...

EDIT:

I've seen that I can implement TextProviderSupport and set it default like says [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/TextProvider.html) and override all its constructors setting a custom createrd resourcebundle with UTF8 inputReader and letting some logs. I've save it and when starting tomcat it says:

> Información: Choosing bean (myTextProvider) for
>   (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)

with this in struts.config:

```
<bean class="com.utils.i18n.UTF8TextProvider" name="myTextProvider"
     type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider" scope="default"/>
     <constant name="struts.xworkTextProvider" value="myTextProvider" />
     <constant name="system" value="myTextProvider" />
```

So, its seems ok. But my class is never instanciated (I only run a sample action that implements action support and write a text with 'getText' and a jsp that have a `<s:text name="">`)

So problem remains...

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 uses the concept of ResourceBundle to load properties files and achive the goals of internalization (i18n) as well as localization (l10n).

The resource bundle is used to keep the key and value pairs for respective languages such as English Resource Bundle can have value as English Text and France Resource Bundle can have value as France Text but the keys are same across.

Resource Bundle can be place in the following places

- ActionClass.properties
- Interface.properties
- BaseClass.properties
- ModelDriven’s Model
- Package.properties
- I18n message key
- Global resource properties

The resource properties are being searched in the above order. At first it looks the resource properties with action class name.properties, if does not found then it looks for interface.properties else goes on till Global resource properties.

There are many tutorials which explain in detail about how to use Resource Bundles in Struts 2. Have a look at the following links:

- http://www.journaldev.com/2304/struts2-resource-bundles-and-localization-example
- http://javatechig.com/java/struts/struts2-localization-example
- http://www.javabeat.net/struts-2-resource-bundle-example/

===============

Update

Regarding loading UTF-8 encoded properties file in Struts 2, you can refer http://javatechig.com/java/struts/struts2-localization-example and see how the Japanese text is being used after encoding it to UTF-8. Since, you mentioned about native2ascii, I am assuming that you know about how to convert a given text to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I know how to do it using native2ascii, but i think its ugly. It makes no sense for me to 'precompile' the .properties files to fix problems with the encoding. The encoding its something that I can manage in my application... why precompile text files?
I want to do it in a proper way.
I want to know if its possible to get the values of a properties file saved in UTF8 working in a native way in struts2 like it can be donde in JSF or in a servlet.

Comment: @eddieferetro The native2ascii is a handy tool build-in in the JDK, which is used to convert a file with ‘non-Latin 1′ or ‘non-Unicode’ characters to ‘Unicode-encoded’ characters. This process is required for properties files containing characters not in ISO-8859-1 character sets. If your character fall within ISO-8859-1 character set; then you won't need to use the native2ascii tool. For more info on ISO-8859-1 character set, refer http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp

Comment: @Baldwinder-singh I know that native2ascii is a tool of the JDK, but I cannot understand why to read a text file needs a precompilation of the text file to fix the encoding... It have no sense. Java6 fixed that BUG letting you to set a Control object when creating the ResourceBundle in which you can manage the loading of the file and, so, fix the encoding problem easily. Also JSF let you easily manage non-ascii .properties files. I only want to know if struts2 lets you do the same. I know what are the alternatives so if there isn't another way to do it I'll do it.

Comment: @eddieferetro Got your point. I also feel that native2ascii isn't a great way to do this and much simpler way should exist. Not entirely sure if there is any simpler way in struts2 or not. However, I chanced upon an eclipse plugin for editing localized properties files at once, through the same screen. It also enables you to perform Non-ASCII character conversion to/from Unicode. You can checkout the plugin at http://eclipse-rbe.sourceforge.net/index.htm. Maybe this will lessen your burden while you look for some simple way to do this in struts2.